# UDP communication fills up memory rapidly

Tags: c#, linux, mono, udp

I have an UDP server on a small linux controller with about 123 MB RAM which is communicating with a single UDP-client. On this linux controller a c# application is running with mono 3.2.8. 
Everything is running fine, except that the udp connection is consuming memory rapidly and GC is collecting it rarely (memory always growing exactly 65,552 bytes between console output 1 and 2).

My client side code is as following:

```
    UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient (port,AddressFamily.InterNetwork);      

    byte[] frame;
    IPEndPoint masterEndPoint = null;

    try
    {
        while(true)
        {            
                    masterEndPoint = null;
                    frame = null;
                    Console.WriteLine("Memory 1: " + GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
                    frame = _udpClient.Receive(ref masterEndPoint);
                    Console.WriteLine("Memory 2: " + GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
           ...
         }
    ...
    }
```

Is there a possibilty that memory isnt growing that fast, like using a buffer instead? If not is it possible to get the unreferenced objects "masterEndPoint" and "frame" collected more rapidly?

Tell me if you need further details!

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you saying there is a memory leak, or that you have memory usage spikes?

Comment: You are using a synchronous (blocking) method to receive messages.  Use an synchronous event instead.  See following webpage.  The examples are using sockets but you can replace the socket with any class that inherits the socket like udpclient. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Paul, thx for your answer. Yes I am running into a memory leak on long term. Anyway much memory is used as well but it is collected after a while with big jumpes (like 10 MB or so).

Comment: Thx jdweng for your answer. I need to respond to every client (IP is unknown) and I dont know the size of the datagram yet, but its usually not that big (like 1k max.), so a buffered receive with this size would be great.
Could you give me a short code example, withought using a bounded socket, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved it by my own. As I assumed that it would be good to always use the same buffer instead of a new one seems to be right, because I don´t have memory spikes anymore (free memory from "top" command is pretty constant now!).

Key method is:

**int length = udpClient.Client.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref endPoint);**

My solution is following:

```
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient (port,AddressFamily.InterNetwork);      
udpClient.DontFragment = true;
...
byte[] frame = new frame[16384];

try
{
    while(true)
    {            
          EndPoint endPoint  = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
          int length = udpClient.Client.ReceiveFrom(frame , ref endPoint);
          ...
          udpClient.Send(responseFrame, responseFrame.Length,(IPEndPoint)endPoint);
    }
...
}
```

If you have any suggestion for a cleaner way, please let me know!

Thanks for your help anyway!